# Приоритет операций JQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Никак не могу понять в чем дело.
Есть 2 текстовых поля в шаблоне

```
<input type="text" id="first">
<input type="text" id="second">
```

Предназначены они для телефонов. Нужно сделать маску и возможность выбора кода. Для этого использую JQuery и 2 плагина к нему:

- intl-tel-input (https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input)
- jQuery-Mask-Plugin (https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin)

Написал код инициализации этих двух полей.

```
function initPhoneMask(fieldId) {
    // инициализируем поле для телефона
    // https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input
    $(fieldId).intlTelInput({
      autoHideDialCode: false,
      nationalMode: false,
      preferredCountries: ['ru'],
      utilsScript: "utils.js"
    });

    // обработчик при изменении телефонного кода
    $(fieldId).on("countrychange", function(e, countryData) {
      if (countryData.iso2 === "ru") {
          $(this).mask('+7 (000) 000-00-00');
      } else {
          $(this).unmask();
      }
    });

    // инициализируем маску для телефона
    // https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin


    $(fieldId).mask('+7 (000) 000-00-00');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initPhoneMask("#first");
    initPhoneMask("#second");
});
```

То есть строка

```
$(fieldId).mask('+7 (000) 000-00-00');
```

инициализирует поле изначально нужной маской, а обработчик вешает/убирает маску если выбран/не выбран код нужной страны.

НО.
При изменении кода страны, на любую другую маска не пропадает. Если убрать код инициализации, то все работает, но вначале поле не инициализируется маской.

Почему так? Мб кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: То есть инициализация перекрывает изменения в обработчике?

Comment: Появляется ошибка - TypeError: e.target.unmask is not a function
Вывожу в консоль 'e' - именно тот элемент, который нужен.

Comment: Та же ошибка. TypeError: e.currentTarget.unmask is not a function

Comment: Вывел сейчас. Там находится обьект того инпута, что нужен. С этим проблем нет.

Comment: Значит проблема не в контексте. Ещё момент, вы точно уверены что методы срабатывают единожды, именно в момент инициализации, и единожды в момент выбора option?

Comment: Да. Проверял через вывод в консоль. Инициализация вызывается единожды. И при каждом изменение кода страны обработчик тоже вызывается единожды. Без вызова инициализации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, решил проблему ручным вызовом события change. Инициализацию убрал.

```
function initPhoneMask(fieldId) {
    // инициализируем поле для телефона
    // https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input
    $(fieldId).intlTelInput({
      autoHideDialCode: false,
      nationalMode: false,
      preferredCountries: ['ru'],
      utilsScript: "utils.js"
    });


    // обработчик при изменении телефонного кода
    $(fieldId).on("countrychange", function(e, countryData) {
      if (countryData.iso2 === "ru") {
          $(this).mask('+7 (000) 000-00-00');
      } else {
          $(this).unmask();
      }
      $(fieldId).val('');
      $(fieldId).val('+' + countryData.dialCode);
    });


    var countryData = $(fieldId).intlTelInput('getSelectedCountryData');
    $(fieldId).trigger('countrychange', [countryData]);

}
```